# How to find the NULL SPACE of the matrix over Finite Field of size 2

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

How to find the NULL SPACE of the matrix over Finite Field of size 2. A.x=0

For example, I have the following matrix. I know how to convert into reduced echolean form. But then how can I find the NULL SPACE matrix from the reduced echolean form. OR Is there any other method apart from reduced echolean form to find the null space of the matrix ?

```
Matrix A            Reduce echolean form(using exlusive(^) operation between rows)
1   1   1   0       1   1   1   0
1   1   0   1   ->  0   1   0   1 
1   0   1   1       0   0   1   1
0   1   1   1       0   0   0   1

9 * 9                               ->     Reduce Row echolean form.
1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0       1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
1   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0       0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0       0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0                   
1   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   0       0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
0   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   0       0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   1       0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0       0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   1       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   
0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

I have to program it in java that I will manage but tell how to find the null space matrix from the reduce echolean form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular matrix, row reducing it has just shown that the rank of the matrix is $4$, hence by the [Rank-Nullity Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem), the nullity is $0$.  Hence the null space is $\{(0,0,0,0\}$.  But in general...

A brute force way to find the null space of $A_{n \times n}$ is to check all $2^n$ vectors $\mathbf{x}$ as to whether or not $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$.  The inefficiency might not be a big deal for small $n$ (especially if we do it on a computer).

In most cases, it'll be more efficient to find the null space of $A$ from its row echelon form $R$ (or maybe even easier would be reduced row echelon form), then we solve $R\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ via back substitution.  The columns without a leading entry correspond to variables which can be considered free, and the remaining variables can be solved in terms of the free variables.

To convert the matrix to reduced row echelon form, we can perform the following row operations:
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 
1 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} \\
\xrightarrow{R_2 \gets R_2+R_1}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 
1 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} \\
\xrightarrow{R_3 \gets R_3+R_1}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 
1 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} \\
\xrightarrow{R_2 \leftrightarrow R_3}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 
1 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} \\
\xrightarrow{R_4 \gets R_4+R_2}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 
1 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix} \\
\xrightarrow{R_4 \gets R_4+R_3}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 
0 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} \\
\xrightarrow{R_1 \gets R_1+R_2}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 
0 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} \\
\xrightarrow{R_1 \gets R_1+R_3}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 
0 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} \\
\xrightarrow{R_2 \gets R_2+R_4}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 
0 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} \\
\xrightarrow{R_3 \gets R_3+R_4}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 
0 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

However, since the rank of the matrix is $4$, we know its invertible, and thus will have reduced row echelon form equal to the identity matrix $I$.

Comment: Can you please show the reduced row echelon form as well as how we find the null space of the matrix given in my question original matrix.

Comment: I know this but, how can I find the NULL SPACE matrix from Row reduce echolean form. OR what is the NULL SPACE matrix, is it zero ?

Comment: In this particular case, the null space is $\{(0,0,0,0)\}$.  It's the set of solutions to the equation $R\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ where $R$ is the reduced row echelon form.  In general, however, this won't be the case (and I explained how to find the null space in general in my original post).

Comment: So if i understand correctly then any matrix with same row and column will have null space of 0.
Because according to the Reduced row echelon form every leading coefficient is 1 and is the only nonzero entry in its column.

I have added one more example for 9*9 matrix just to clarify that it's null space is 0 correct ? So please have a look at original question and let me know if it's reduced echolean form is correct and it's null matrix will also be zero.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it's not correct.  E.g. the all-$0$ matrix has equal rows and columns, and the null space is the whole space.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your last comment. Sorry I am little slow.

Comment: E.g. the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$ has null space $\mathbb{F}^3$, and it has the same rows and columns.  What the null space is depends on what the reduced row echelon form looks like.

Comment: Can you please tell me any link or tutorial or something where I can learn what row reduced echolean form is and also about null space matrix. Because what I have understand is that row reduced ecolean is like identity matrix every leading coefficient is 1 and is the only nonzero entry in its column.

Answer (score 0):

If you go on wikipedia it says, " the null space of A is the same as the solution set to the homogeneous system."http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28linear_algebra%29

It is defined as the homogenous solution of Ax = 0 in http://science.kennesaw.edu/~plaval/math3260/rowcolspaces.pdf if you do not trust wikipedia. That should help you on your way.